# Rider freezes when installing app on AVD for the second time

Tags: macos, xamarin, android-emulator, jetbrains-ide, rider

I am using Rider for Mac.
I create an AVD in AVD Manager.
I run my .net Xamarin App from Rider.
When running the app for the first  everything is ok.
When I try to run the app the second time Rider freezes while installing the app(I cannot click on anything in the Rider UI).
In Activity Monitor Rider appears as "(Not Responding)".
This is the last thing I see in the UI:

[image]

The idea.log file does not appear in /Users/*******/Library/Logs/JetBrains/Rider2020.2 or any of the other log files

[image]

The only way I can unfreeze Rider is to use Activity Monitor to kill the Emulator.
If I delete the AVD and make a new one everything works the first time and then it starts freezing up again.
What can I do to stop this from happening?

Comment: Report this to the Rider support. If you cannot find the relevant logs, they will guide you to what exactly to send.

Comment: @Para did you find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: @Reza no :( it just started working on it's own accord and I don't know how to fix it is it happens again :( please tell me if you find out. Sorry I cannot help more :(

Comment: I’m having the same issue, always on the second+ debug. Usually have to delete the avd and recreate, but that’s annoying